# How to add my own file template to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

When you right click in a folder, Eclipse pops up a context menu that allows you to create different kinds of files. I'd like to add an option to add a kind of file of my own (with some constant data I'll want to put there). Is there an easy way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I know of two ways (one tested and of other I am not sure) in which you can extend the **Default** `new submenu` of package explorers popup menu.

**The short, working and tested way is to use `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`.**

**>>Note:** You will need a wizard to contribute to the **Default** `new submenu` of package explorers popup menu. You can do this using this link [eSpeed development with Eclipse wizards](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-custwiz/) (the same one provided by @Ed Burnette)

Steps to follow:

1. For this example I have created a dummy test wizard with the **id** `testwizard.wizards.TestWizard`.
2. Now create an extension of `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions`. For this example I am just contributing to the **Java development perspective**. You can have multiple instance of it for different perspectives. Therefore, the **targetId** is `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective`.
3. Now right click on the **perspectiveExtension** and select **newWizardShortcut**
4. Set the **id** of the **newWizardShortcut** as your custom wizards id i.e. `testwizard.wizards.TestWizard` in my case.
5. Restart your application. Now **don't forget** to reset the perspective, otherwise your addition to the popup menu won't be visible.

**>>Plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>    
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
      <category
            name="Test Wizards"
            id="TestWizard">
      </category>
      <wizard
            name="HTML Test Wizard"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="TestWizard"
            class="testwizard.wizards.TestWizard"
            id="testwizard.wizards.TestWizard">
      </wizard>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
         <newWizardShortcut
               id="testwizard.wizards.TestWizard">
         </newWizardShortcut>
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

**>>Output**

[image: Output]

**The long and untested way is to use `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent`. And I am not sure whether it will work or not. Providing it just for reading and exploration purpose**

Use these links:

1. [Navigator Content 1](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2010/05/16/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-21-return-of-the-popup-menu-displaying-resources/)
2. [Navigator Content 2](http://cvalcarcel.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/writing-an-eclipse-plug-in-part-20-return-of-the-popup-menu-for-an-empty-navigator/)

In the end I will suggest you to use first approach as it is simple and elegant. Read and use second method if you are writing a new perspective, view etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create an Eclipse plug-in and create a New File wizard. There's a great tutorial on how to do it over on developerworks:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-custwiz/

See also:

- http://www.eclipse-tips.com/tips/10

Comment: As per his question, he wants a way to include a wizard (file type) in the **New** submenu. The links you have shared are for creating a new wizard only.